# Return XML of Post Metadata

Tags: wpdb, map

All of my posts in one category (i.e. Location) have two custom fields: latitude and longitude. I would like to return an XML or JSON of all those posts (title, latitude, longitude) for use as Google Maps markers.

I can't simply call out to a stand-alone php file to return my data as I would like to access my data through $wpdb.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to create a custom XML page template in the exact format you need.  If you look at the code below taken from the WordPress XML exporter you can see that the data it returns contains the normal stuff we see in a typical WordPress loop.

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . get_bloginfo('charset') . '"?' . ">\n";
?>
<!-- This is a WordPress eXtended RSS file generated by WordPress as an export of your blog. -->
<!-- It contains information about your blog's posts, comments, and categories. -->
<!-- You may use this file to transfer that content from one site to another. -->
<!-- This file is not intended to serve as a complete backup of your blog. -->

<!-- To import this information into a WordPress blog follow these steps. -->
<!-- 1. Log into that blog as an administrator. -->
<!-- 2. Go to Tools: Import in the blog's admin panels (or Manage: Import in older versions of WordPress). -->
<!-- 3. Choose "WordPress" from the list. -->
<!-- 4. Upload this file using the form provided on that page. -->
<!-- 5. You will first be asked to map the authors in this export file to users -->
<!--    on the blog.  For each author, you may choose to map to an -->
<!--    existing user on the blog or to create a new user -->
<!-- 6. WordPress will then import each of the posts, comments, and categories -->
<!--    contained in this file into your blog -->

<?php the_generator('export');?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/<?php echo WXR_VERSION; ?>/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/<?php echo WXR_VERSION; ?>/"
>

<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); ?></title>
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss("description") ?></description>
    <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></pubDate>
    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=<?php bloginfo_rss('version'); ?></generator>
    <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
    <wp:wxr_version><?php echo WXR_VERSION; ?></wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url><?php echo wxr_site_url(); ?></wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url><?php bloginfo_rss('url'); ?></wp:base_blog_url>
<?php if ( $cats && ($terms == 'all' || $terms == 'cats')) : foreach ( $cats as $c ) : ?>
    <wp:category><wp:category_nicename><?php echo $c->slug; ?></wp:category_nicename><wp:category_parent><?php echo $c->parent ? $cats[$c->parent]->name : ''; ?></wp:category_parent><?php wxr_cat_name($c); ?><?php wxr_category_description($c); ?></wp:category>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
<?php if ( $tags && ($terms == 'all' || $terms == 'tags')) : foreach ( $tags as $t ) : ?>
    <wp:tag><wp:tag_slug><?php echo $t->slug; ?></wp:tag_slug><?php wxr_tag_name($t); ?><?php wxr_tag_description($t); ?></wp:tag>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php if ($post_ids) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->in_the_loop = true;  // Fake being in the loop.
        // fetch 20 posts at a time rather than loading the entire table into memory
        while ( $next_posts = array_splice($post_ids, 0, 20) ) {
            $where = "WHERE ID IN (".join(',', $next_posts).")";
            $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts $where ORDER BY post_date_gmt ASC");
                foreach ($posts as $post) {
                    setup_postdata($post); ?>
<item>
<title><?php echo apply_filters('the_title_rss', $post->post_title); ?></title>
<link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
<dc:creator><?php echo wxr_cdata(get_the_author()); ?></dc:creator>
<?php wxr_post_taxonomy() ?>

<guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
<description></description>
<content:encoded><?php echo wxr_cdata( apply_filters('the_content_export', $post->post_content) ); ?></content:encoded>
<wp:post_date><?php echo $post->post_date; ?></wp:post_date>
<wp:post_date_gmt><?php echo $post->post_date_gmt; ?></wp:post_date_gmt>
    </item>
<?php } } } ?>
</channel>
</rss>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I used the method you described - Too easy :D